# find() problems with boost bimap

Tags: c++, boost, bimap

I have the following code:

```
wxString getColorName(const wxColour& color)
{
    typedef ColorComboBox::ColorMap::right_const_iterator ConstColorIterator;
    ColorComboBox::ColorMap colorMap = ColorComboBox::getDefaultChoices();
    ConstColorIterator it = colorMap.right.find(color);
    return it != colorMap.right.end() ? it->second :
            ColorComboBox::CUSTOM_COLOR;
}
```

where ColorMap is defined

```
typedef boost::bimaps::bimap \
            <wxString, boost::bimaps::vector_of<wxColour> > \
            ColorMap;
```

and I keep getting a long template error that basically says the find function does not exist. However

```
ColorMap::left_const_iterator it = choices_.left.find(GetValue());
```

compiles fine.
I have a hunch the find function is only defined in certain collection types of bimap. I cannot use a set_of wxColours because wxColour is not comparable. (What would that even mean?) I also tried changing the collection type to list_of, but that didn't work either. My whole point in using bimap was so that I could find values going either way. Am I using the wrong container? Is there another collection type I can use for wxColour that will allow me to use the find function?

**EDIT:**
I ended up creating my own container class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Bimap allows you to define the [mapping type](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/controlling_collection_types.html) of each side. If your application needs to perform quick searches, use map/multimap or unordered_map/unordered_multimap based mappings. Please read the documentation and remember that each map view is modeled after the equivalent STL containers, so they share the same constraints and interface:

- `set_of` ( ordered, unique ) --> `std::map`
- `multiset_of` ( ordered ) --> `std::multimap`
- `unordered_set_of` ( hashed, unique ) --> `std::unordered_map`
- `unordered_multiset_of` ( hashed ) --> `std::unordered_multimap`
- `list_of` ( sequenced ) --> list_map ( `std::list<pair>` )
- `vector_of` ( random access ) --> vector_map ( `std::vector<pair>` )
- `unconstrained_set_of` --> not mapped

I do not understand why you choose a `vector_of<wxColour>`, maybe it was just because `set_of<wxColour>` (the default) didn't compiled... in this case, as you stated, you need to define your own comparison operator to tell the bimap how to order these items. The vector-mapping and list-mapping are there to allow you to create bimaps that preserve the insertion order of your relations.

In your case, what you want is a [`unordered_set_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/reference/unordered_set_of_reference.html). You will need to define your own hash functor for `wxColour`. You can use Boost.Hash to implement it.

Best regards

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is good so I upvoted you even though I went with another solution.